# Correct use of MVVM and MouseEvent Handling

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My XAML looksl ike this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Dexel.Editor.Views.UI_Sketches.UiSketchCanvas"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:Dexel.Editor.Views.CustomControls"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{DynamicResource  BG}">
<Grid>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding mouseTestCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger >
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Transparent"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="White">
                </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

In my ViewModel I have this code to handle the command:

```
public ICommand MouseTestCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mouseTestCommand == null)
            {
                _mouseTestCommand = new CommandBase(eventArgs => mouseTest(eventArgs), null);
            }
            return _mouseTestCommand;
        }
    }
```

which calls this function:

```
private void MouseTest(object eventArgs)
    {
        var test = (MouseButtonEventArgs)eventArgs;
        var source = (Rectangle)test.OriginalSource;
        var rectangle = source.DataContext as SketchRectangleViewModel;
        Selected = rectangle;

    }
```

Is the implementation I use right now even MVVM? If so is the code I use right now bad? I'm not sure if there is a better way but I somehow have to get the information where the user clicked and recieve the DataContext if it is an rectangle.

Problems I see already:

- Somehow need to check that the recieved original source is actually a `rectangle` and not the `canvas`

Comment: You should explain what problem your code is solving, not how (mouse down, rectangle, etc.).

Comment: Using of `MouseButtonEventArgs` in view-model breaks MVVM. You need handle `PreviewMouseDown` on `Rectangle` as said by @nikita-b passing its `DataContext` as `CommandParameter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks OK to me. You do leak views to your viewmodel though. Some better approaches:

1. Handle event on rectangle itself. It will allow you to bind it's `DataContext` directly to command parameter. This should eliminate the leak.
2. Use items control that supports selection, [i.e. ListBox](https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/01/31/999-using-a-canvas-as-the-items-panel-for-a-listbox/). Then you will be able to bind to `SelectedItem` property directly without any events.

Other minor things:

1. `Base` postfix is normally used to indicate an abstract class. Might want to remove it from your command class, since it is clearly not abstract.
2. I'm not sure where this whole thing with lazy initialization is coming from (it is not the first time I see it), but it makes no sense to me. What's the point in lazy initialization for commands? Just use regular readonly property:

   ```
   public ICommand MouseTestCommand {get;}
   ```

   And initialize it in constructor. It is cleaner and requires less code to write. Also you might want to create another constructor for your command, that passes `null` for `CanExecute` by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to correct my code. Quick question though: If I handle my Events in the rectangle how do I get the position of my MouseClick and the DataContext to my ViewModel?